# How to add sub menu items clicking on MenuItems in xamarin.forms MasterDetailPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, master-detail

Hi I am trying to add submenu items When clicking on the Menuitems in MasterDatailPage.My master page xaml is like

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HomeMaster"
             Title="Master"
             Icon="hamburger.png">
  <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenuItems"
              SeparatorVisibility="None"
              HasUnevenRows="true"
              ItemTapped="ListViewMenuItems_ItemTapped"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="2"
              Source="User.png" HeightRequest="100" x:Name="userImg"/>
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             Padding="20,10,0,10"
                             Spacing="20">

                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                         WidthRequest="40"
                         HeightRequest="40"
                         VerticalOptions="Center" />

                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                         FontSize="Medium"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         TextColor="Black"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10" Padding="20,10, 0, 0" IsVisible="{Binding IsExtraControlsVisible}">
                            <Label Text="Test Definition" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black"/>
                            <Label Text="Maptest" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black"/>
                         </StackLayout>
                       </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

in my .cs file ItemTapped is like

```
private void ListViewMenuItems_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.Item as MRPHomeMenuItem;
            if (item.Id == 0)
            {
            item.IsExtraControlsVisible = true;
            }
        }
```

When i click on submenu items total cell is calling because of I given stack layout viewcell.How to add these submenu items in separate cells when clicking on Menuitems  like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35gZz.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a expandable `ListView`, to achieve this, we need to group the items of our list, means implementing the `GroupHeaderTemplate` of the `ListView`.

You may check the blogs here:

[Xamarin.Forms Expandable ListView](http://www.compliancestudio.io/blog/xamarin-forms-expandable-listview).

[Expandable ListView in Xamarin Forms using Grouping](https://umohammed.wordpress.com/2016/12/11/expandable-listview-in-xamarin-forms-using-grouping/amp/).